# ReactJS/Firebase: How to set a timestamp field to null/undefined?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want the ability for users not to select a date.

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
<MobileDatePicker
label={"Date From"}
inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
disablePast={true}
value={datefrom}
minDate={new Date()}
onChange={(newValue) => {
setDateFrom(format(newValue, 'MM/dd/yyyy'));
if (dateto == '') {
setDateTo(format(newValue, 'MM/dd/yyyy'));
}
}}
renderInput={(params) => <TextField variant="outlined" {...params} helperText={null} fullWidth />}
/>
```

I thought this would work:

```
<Button onClick={(newValue) => {setDateFrom(null);}}>CLEAR DATES</Button>
```

And while it clears the date, it does not allow me to save a blank field

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to ignore undefined value for this case, you can conditionally spread object.

Something like this should work.

```
await setDoc(docRef, {
  mandatoryField: "value",
  ...(dateTo === "" ? {} : {timeStamp: dateTo}  )

})
```

If you want to ignore all undefined value for future usage you can initialize firestore setting as below.

```
import { getFirestore, initializeFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'; // Firebase v9+

// Must be called before getFirestore()
initializeFirestore(app, {
  ignoreUndefinedProperties: true
});
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
```